# Is there a system that support job contracts?

Tags: contracts

I am wondering if there is a system that support bitcoin contracts like:

If I made a deposit to a wallet - this wallet takes 10% of the BTC and transfer it automatically to another wallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a payment API similar to:

http://dev.blockcypher.com/#payments_summary

This gives you a new address for which any deposit will be automatically transferred to another address of your choice. I'm sure they could implement the 10% fee transferred to a separate wallet very easily.